Cookies not being sent with requests, resulting in undefined token in Express backend
I'm facing an issue where the access_token cookie is not being sent with requests, resulting in the token being undefined in my Express backend. I've verified that the token is not present in the browser's document.cookie. Here are the relevant parts of my implementation:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";
import Visibility from "@mui/icons-material/Visibility";
import VisibilityOff from "@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { toast, ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const style = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  width: 300,
  bgcolor: "background.paper",
  border: "2px none #000",
  boxShadow: 24,
  borderRadius: 2,
  p: 4,
};

const ChangePasswordModal = ({ handleClose, onUpdatePassword }) => {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [showConfirmPassword, setShowConfirmPassword] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    currentPassword: "",
    newPassword: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (formData.newPassword !== formData.confirmPassword) {
      toast.error("New password and confirm password do not match");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const token = Cookies.get("access_token"); // Get token from cookies
      console.log("Token from cookies:", token); // Add this for debugging
      console.log("All cookies:", Cookies.get()); // Log all cookies
      console.log("Document cookie:", document.cookie); // Log document.cookie
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/changepassword",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, // Add token to headers
          },
          credentials: "include", //Ensure cookies are sent with the request
          body: JSON.stringify({
            currentPassword: formData.currentPassword,
            newPassword: formData.newPassword,
          }),
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        toast.error(errorData.message);
      } else {
        setFormData({
          currentPassword: "",
          newPassword: "",
          confirmPassword: "",
        });
        handleClose();
        toast.success("Password changed successfully");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error changing password:", error.message);
      toast.error("An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={style}>
      <IconButton
        sx={{ position: "absolute", top: 8, right: 8 }}
        onClick={handleClose}
      >
        <CloseIcon />
      </IconButton>

      <TextField
        label="Enter current password"
        variant="outlined"
        type="password"
        name="currentPassword"
        fullWidth
        margin="normal"
        value={formData.currentPassword}
        onChange={handleChange}
        sx={{ mb: 2 }}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Enter new password"
        variant="outlined"
        type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
        name="newPassword"
        fullWidth
        margin="normal"
        value={formData.newPassword}
        onChange={handleChange}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <IconButton
              aria-label="toggle password visibility"
              onClick={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
              edge="end"
            >
              {showPassword ? (
                <VisibilityOff fontSize="small" />
              ) : (
                <Visibility fontSize="small" />
              )}
            </IconButton>
          ),
        }}
        sx={{ mb: 2 }}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Confirm new password"
        variant="outlined"
        type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
        name="confirmPassword"
        fullWidth
        margin="normal"
        value={formData.confirmPassword}
        onChange={handleChange}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <IconButton
              aria-label="toggle password visibility"
              onClick={() => setShowConfirmPassword(!showConfirmPassword)}
              edge="end"
            >
              {showConfirmPassword ? (
                <VisibilityOff fontSize="small" />
              ) : (
                <Visibility fontSize="small" />
              )}
            </IconButton>
          ),
        }}
        sx={{ mb: 2 }}
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        sx={{
          mt: 2,
          backgroundColor: "#0b5fae",
          ":hover": { backgroundColor: "#0a54a0" },
        }}
        fullWidth
      >
        Update Password
      </Button>
      <ToastContainer />
    </Box>
  );
};

ChangePasswordModal.propTypes = {
  handleClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onUpdatePassword: PropTypes.func.isRequired, // Callback for password update
};

export default ChangePasswordModal;


Backend Express server configuration:
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("./utils/passport");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const swaggerJsDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");

const uploadController = require("./controllers/upload.controller");
const db = require("./models");

const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// use of cookieParser
app.use(cookieParser());

// use of express-session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }, // Set secure to true in production when using HTTPS
  })
);

// use of Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

if (
  !process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ||
  !process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ||
  !process.env.S3_BUCKET ||
  !process.env.MONGODB_URL
) {
  console.error("Environment variables not set properly.");
  process.exit(1);
}

db.mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("MongoDB connection error:", err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

app.use("/api/upload", uploadController);
// Import routes
require("./routes/project.routes")(app);
require("./routes/workspace.routes")(app);
require("./routes/auth.routes")(app);

const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    openapi: "3.0.0",
    info: {
      title: "TaskWise API",
      version: "1.0.0",
      description:
        "TaskWise is a task management API that allows users to manage workspaces, projects, tasks efficiently.",
    },
    servers: [{ url: "http://localhost:8080" }],
  },
  apis: ["./controllers/*.js", "./routes/*.js"],
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`TaskWise Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


Authentication Middleware:
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

const ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.access_token; // Extract the token from cookies

  console.log("Token:", token); // Debugging

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Token is required" });
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = decoded; // Attach the decoded user information to the request
    console.log("Authenticated user:", req.user); // Add this line
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res
      .status(403)
      .json({ message: "Token is not valid, or it's expired" });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  ensureAuthenticated,
};

Auth Routes:
module.exports = (app) => {
  const passport = require("../utils/passport");
  // const passport = require("passport");

  const {
    registerUser,
    loginUser,
    signOutUser,
    forgotPassword,
    verifyResetCode,
    resendOTP,
    resetPassword,
    changePassword,
  } = require("../controllers/auth.controller.js");

  const { ensureAuthenticated } = require("../utils/auth.js");

  const router = require("express").Router();

  // Register a new user
  router.post("/auth/register", registerUser);

  // Login a user
  router.post("/auth/login", loginUser);

  // Logout a user
  router.post("/auth/logout", signOutUser);

  //Google OAuth routes
  router.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
  );

  router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
    (req, res) => {
      // Successful authentication, redirect to client
      res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/projects"); // Adjust the URL as needed
    }
  );

  // Route to handle forgot password (send reset code)
  router.post("/auth/forgotpassword", forgotPassword);

  // Route to handle verification of the reset code
  router.post("/auth/verification", verifyResetCode);

  // Route to handle resending the OTP
  router.post("/auth/resendotp", resendOTP);

  // Route to handle resetting the password
  router.post("/auth/resetpassword", resetPassword);

  // Route to handle change password
  router.post("/auth/changepassword", changePassword, ensureAuthenticated);

  app.use("/api", router);
};


Change Password Logic:
changePassword: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { currentPassword, newPassword } = req.body;
      const userId = req.user._id;

      // Find the user by userId
      const user = await UserModel.findById(userId);

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
      }

      // Compare the current password with the password in the database
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(currentPassword, user.password);

      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid current password" });
      }

      // Hash the new password
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10);
      user.password = hashedPassword;

      await user.save();
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Password changed successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error changing password:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
  },

Despite setting the credentials: 'include' in the fetch request and ensuring the backend uses the cookie-parser middleware, the token is still undefined when trying to access it from req.cookies in the backend.
Verified that the cookie is being set in the browser.
Ensured that cookie-parser middleware is used before any route handlers.
Verified the CORS configuration to allow credentials.
Why is the access_token cookie not being sent with the request to the backend?
Are there any additional configurations needed for CORS or cookies to ensure they are sent with requests?
What might I be missing in my setup?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Due to httpOnly: true, you won't be able to read the cookie via client-side JS

OK, so is there any workaround or should I remove the "httpOnly: true" ?

I would say just stop trying to read the cookies client-side. Why are you extracting the cookie value and putting it into an Authorization header? The server can just read the HTTP-only cookie from the request already

The problem is I am getting cannot read properties of undefined reading _id in my backend console, after clicking on Change Password button in my ChangePasswordModal component.

I had encountered this issue before when my backend and frontend were running in different domain/ip, so you have to set the correct domain while adding the cookie from server side i believe.
